# How to use bitwise operators?

Tags: c, function, operators, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to write a function that can negate an integer without using the - operator.

The function is int negate(int n), can someone give me insight on how to do this in C programming?

Comment: You mean something like `n = ~n + 1;` ?

Comment: Assuming your machine uses Two's Complement: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement

Answer (score 1):

I speak C# but it should be the same in C. Try this.

```
int negate(int n){
    return ~n + 1; // or you could use ~(n - 1)
}
```

Take care.